# Jekyll post_url -- what am I missing?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I am using Jekyll and Github pages, testing locally using `bundle exec jekyll serve`. Everything else works fine so far.

My posts are in a `/_posts` folder off of the root, and are outputted correctly.

I cannot seem to get `{% post_url %}` working within posts for other internal posts, no matter what I do.

### Example / Question

- In my `_posts` folder, I have a post with a file name of `2011-04-14-free-million-dollar-idea-package-carriers-b2b-success.markdown`

  - This shows up on my site at `[root]/2011/04/free-million-dollar-idea-package-carriers-b2b-success/`
- My config specifies `permalink:   /:year/:month/:title`

I have tried the following references within `{% post_url %}` from another post, to try to link to the post:

- 2011-04-14-free-million-dollar-idea-package-carriers-b2b-success

  - Based on the file name of the post, which I thought was what I should be referencing
- /2011/04/free-million-dollar-idea-package-carriers-b2b-success/

  - Based on the URL that the post actually resides on at my web site
- 2011/04/free-million-dollar-idea-package-carriers-b2b-success/

  - Without the leading slash
- /2011/04/free-million-dollar-idea-package-carriers-b2b-success

  - Without the trailing slash
- 2011/04/free-million-dollar-idea-package-carriers-b2b-success

  - Without either slash

Each one yields the error:

> Could not parse name of post [reference] in tag 'post_url'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If your post file name is `2011-04-14-free-million-dollar-idea-package-carriers-b2b-success.md` or `.markdown` the syntax is :

```
[Link text]({% post_url 2011-04-14-free-million-dollar-idea-package-carriers-b2b-success %})
```

Comment: You are indeed correct. The issue I was having ended up being something entirely different. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Also check that the front-matter `date` value matches the date in the post's file name.

[(Some versions) of `jekyll` + `safe_yaml` can't find the post if the date on the file-name doesn't match the date in the front-matter data.](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/1886)

Answer (score 1):

Was pulling my hair out until I realized that if a post isn't published, it doesn't "exist" to be linked.

Posts must be published, assuming you're only building Jekyll with published posts. I suspect this might also be a problem if you're linking to a future post.